# Vista PS2 Mouse Does not work

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, ps2

I am trying to use a PS2 mouse with my Vista Home Ultimate (32-bit) machine. Vista installs the driver but says cannot load driver error code 10 in device manager. Driver is Microsoft 6.0.6001.18000 dated 6/21/2006 and is the moust updated version. (I also have a PS2 keyboard connected and working as well as a USB mouse.)

Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to sound nuts, but have you tried rebooting? I had this issue with a computer I just built for my father -- I used nothing but USB mice and keyboards while building it, then got it to his place and discovered his were PS/2. The mouse was failing (pointer stuck in the middle, same symptoms as yours). I tried searching here first, in fact. :)

After about 45 minutes of exercising Google-Fu from my phone, I gave up and tried a reboot. Lo and behold, the mouse worked perfectly, and has since.

Comment: It sounds crazy yeah but it worked. I wonder why keyboard worked without rebooting. Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely a good thing to try, generally adding a PS/2 device won't be detected until after a restart.